# How Can I get Nested JSON to my DataSource ... React Native

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native

Help me. How Can I get  Nested JSON to my DataSource ... React Native
why it's so hard or I'm a newbie i can't do this.

```
   {
    success: true,
    result: 
    {
        types: [],
        information: {
                        Campaigns: {
                        isEntity: true,
                        label: "Campaigns",
                        singular: "Campaign"
                        },
                        
                        Vendors: {
                        isEntity: true,
                        label: "Vendors",
                        singular: "Vendor"
                        },
                        
                        ProductTaxes: {
                        isEntity: false,
                        label: "ProductTaxes",
                        singular: "ProductTaxes"
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

---

I can do this and perfectly in Java (Native Android)
with Iterator while hasNext

but in React Native I can't do this :(

I need to get label to show in Listview
and condition is isEntity = "true"
Is isEntity = "false" don't show it in Listview

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { users } from '../config/data';

class Feed extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        mSessionName:null,
        isLoading: true,
    };

  }


  onLearnMore = (user) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { ...user });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const {state} = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(state.params.sessionName);
    console.log(state.params.u_url);
    console.log(state.params.u_url+"/webservice.php?operation=listtypes&sessionName="+state.params.sessionName);
    return fetch(state.params.u_url+"/webservice.php?operation=listtypes&sessionName="+state.params.sessionName)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.result),
      }, function() {
        // do something with new state
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }
  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
         return (
           <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
             <ActivityIndicator />
           </View>
         );
       }

       return (
         <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
           <ListView
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.information.Campaigns}, {rowData.information.Campaigns}</Text>}
           />
         </View>
       );
  }
}

export default Feed;
```

output : >>
[My output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSeIB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition to renderRow:

```
renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.information.Campaigns}, {rowData.information.Campaigns}</Text>} // not sure why repeating
```

but as per your comment it should be:

```
renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.information.Campaigns.isEntity ? rowData.information.Campaigns.label : </view> }</Text>}
```

if need to show more data then I suggest you to make function to render row and add your view structure for data needs to be displayed.

Comment: it's show error T_T


 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Campaigns' of undefined

Comment: what are you getting for `console.log(rowData)`

Comment: my rowData reurn (found object with keys{isEntity , label, singular})
if pointer to isEntity / label / singular is Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

I think this method is static is not dynamically

"rowData.information.Campaigns.isEntity"

Comment: Okay. If you can see object in console then you can right click the desired variable and get the path, use it with `rowData`(copied path - it would be like `.information.Campaigns` )

Comment: from **'dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.result)'**
I used to use  **<Text>{rowData.information.Campaigns.singular}</Text>**

it's return error again  Cannot read property 'Campaigns' of undefined

I don't know what's happens

Comment: from error,it seems you do not have data in `information`. please check console.log of it and verify the data type of `information` if exists. Then use the notation access other properties.